# Branch on lazily evaluated assignment in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, conditional-statements, lazy-evaluation

In Kotlin, how do you branch on multiple conditions, evaluated lazily, some of which may involve variable assignment?

For example, here is a C++ version of this scenario:

```cpp
int b;
if (a > 0 && (b = getB()) > 0)
    branch1(a, b);
else
    branch2();
```

Here is a Swift version, assuming a guard scenario where return is acceptable. Using `Optional` is a bit hacky, but it works:

```swift
guard a > 0, let b = Optional(getB()), b > 0
    else { branch2(); return }
branch1(a, b)
```

In the examples, `branch1` and `branch2` are function calls for explanatory purposes, but may be inline code in real-world use. Having to factor that code into separate methods may be undesirable.

Kotlin, like Swift, has assignments that don't evaluate to the assigned value. However, Kotlin doesn't have a direct equivalent to `guard`, which supports assignment with multiple lazy conditions. What is an eloquent way in Kotlin to lazily evaluate a condition that includes an assignment?

Comment: The question says “`a` […] is true” — I'm guessing that should be “`a` […] is not null”?

Comment: Also, why does the code pass `b` into `branch1()`, when `b` can only be `true` at that point?

Comment: @gidds Great feedback! I had `b` and `a` as types that evaluated directly to booleans for simplicity, but it ended up making things more confusing. I rewrote the question with more clear data types and expressions, and focused on the core issue, which is lazy evaluation with assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an elegant solution to this sort of construct; here are some uglier options.

Perhaps the most direct translation would be along the lines of:

```
val a: A
if (b && r != null && getA()?.also{ a = it } != null)
    branch1(b, r, a) // ERROR: Variable 'a' must be initialized
else
    branch2()
```

…except that the compiler isn't (currently) smart enough to see that `a` will always have been assigned by the time it's used in `branch1()`.

You could work around that by making it a `var`, and giving it an initial value — but the only likely value is `null`, which means making the field nullable and then having to add `!!` when you use it.  All of which makes it rather ugly — even though the condition is in one place, and `getA()` is called only if needed:

```
var a: A? = null
if (b && r != null && getA()?.also{ a = it } != null)
    branch1(b, r, a!!)
else
    branch2()
```

A variation might be to split the condition, and always assign `a`:

```
val a = if (b && r != null) getA() else null
if (a != null)
    branch1(b, r!!, a)
else
    branch2()
```

That works — but now the compiler can't tell that `r` is non-null, so you need `!!` there instead.

You could make that slightly simpler with a `when` (though you need to flip the cases):

```
when (val a = if (b && r != null) getA() else null) {
    null -> branch2()
    else -> branch1(b, r!!, a)
}
```

Ultimately, the problem is that you're trying to get side-effects that only happen under some circumstances, and *then* use those side-effects back in the condition and the resulting branch — and that's as confusing for humans as it is for the compiler.  (C was my main language for many years, and I always found embedded assignments awkward…)  If I saw such code, I'd consider rewriting it in a more straightforward way, for the benefit of whoever had to maintain it.  In this case, that might be:

```
if (b && r != null) {
    val a = getA()
    if (a != null)
        branch1(b, r, a)
    else
        branch2()
} else
    branch2()
```

This is longer-winded, and has to duplicate the `branch2()` call (though there might be ways around that if the call were very complicated, e.g. by setting a flag).  But it's arguably easier to follow (especially as regards seeing when `getA()` might be called); `a` doesn't need to be mutable; and the compiler can see that both `r` and `a` cannot be null in the `branch1()` call, and so smart-casts them.

(By the way, all of these assume that `getA()` could be expensive and/or have side-effects; if not, there would be simpler alternatives that called it unnecessarily.  Conversely, if more than one assignment were needed, all of these options would get more complicated.)

Comment: You can make local variables `lateinit var` so you could use that with `also` for A. Not necessarily any cleaner than solutions using `!!`.